# In k-fold-cross validation, do we train algorithm on (k-1) subsets one by one or on combined (k-1) subsets at once?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I mean to say, lets say I have 10 subsets (`set1, set2,.....set10`) of a training set. To perform 10 fold CV, according to me I should train my algorithm on `rbind(set2,set3.....set9,set10)` and test it on `set1`. Then I will train it on `rbind( set1,set3,set4,....set10)` and test it on `set2` and so on. Am I correct ?

I have a feeling that we train algorithm on `set2`, `set3`....`set10` one by one and test it on `set1`. This way we have 9 sets of predictions on set1 and then we can average it out. Which one is the correct way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding that one set is left our for testing and combined remaining sets are used for testing is correct.

Please refer the question and second answer @
[10 fold cross validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619700/10-fold-cross-validation?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The situation is similar to what is depicted here:

[image]

As a side note, you are better off if you pay attention that the prior probabilities of your class (to be predicted) are approximately equal in all `(set1, set2,.....set10)`.

This is called **stratified k-fold cross validation**, the folds are selected so that the mean response value is approximately equal in all the folds. In the case of a dichotomous classification, this means that each fold contains roughly the same proportions of the two types of class labels.